# how to split an array with a constant size in python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to achieve following things

**Example**

```
array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

and an `integer i`. Every time I want to get an **i-length** sub-array from this array. `If i=3`

**Expected/Required Output :** 
get a sub-array [1,2,3] in first time, in second time I get[4,5,6]. Is there anyway to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this generator:

```
def slice_generator(a, i):
    ind =[[j+l for l in range(i)] for j in a[::i][0:-1]]
    for s in ind:
        yield [a[k] for k in s]
```

To test:

```
a = range(10)
i = 3
# create 
a_slice_generator = slice_generator(a,i)
# iterate
for slice in a_slice_generator:
   print slice
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

You can also `next(a_slice_generator)` to move to the next slice.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**Use Of** `array_chunk`.

```
$input_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 3));
```

**output**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10

        )


)
```